# Convert response as u041d u0438 to readable format

Tags: c#, facebook, encoding, response

Work with Facebook API and my response from request is:

```
\u041d\u0438\u043a\u0438\u0442\u0430
```

How can I convert this string to normal readable string. I think format must be UTF8. I work with C#.

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8(v=vs.110).aspx) posting on MSDN includes code to convert from UTF8 to something more easily readable.

Comment: That is for sure not the _whole_ API response. The API returns JSON, and that’s how unicode is escaped in JSON. Really _all_ you have to do, is decode the JSON.